# how to define which mysql driver to use on pentaho kettle 4.2.0?

Tags: mysql, repository, driver, pentaho, kettle

I'm having difficulty to connect to a MySQL pentaho data integration repository.
Kitchen.sh keeps asking for org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver instead of desired com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.
How to define correct driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put your jar file of actual JDBC-Driver into /libext/JDBC
2. a. Create new databse connection
   b. Choose connection type "***Generic Database***",
   c. Set the property "***Custom Driver Class Name***" to "***com.mysql.jdbc.Driver***"
   d. Set "***Custpm Connection URL***" to "*jdbc:mysql://**myhost**:3306/**mydb***", where ***myhost*** is your host name, ***mydb*** - your database name.
   e. Set ***username*** and ***password*** of your DB
3. Use that connection to connect to repository